# SEO: large numerical hashes vs short ones

Tags: seo

We have a URL with cool names of things, for example:

domain.com/name-of-a-news-with-cool-keywords-4673612453

My question is about the last hash, the hash you usually use to get the ID of the news from your database.

Our application is already done and built in a way that the new articles ID are not incremental in database, they are "random" INT (this is done because we use a encoder/decoder function to generate alphanumeric keys as Youtube).

A friend of mine told me to change this to shorter numbers (that would implied to change a lot of things in the application and internal logic).

The SEO question is:   is so important to have short numbers as a hash ?

I mean ... is it really a SEP improvement to have

```
 domain.com/name-of-a-news-with-cool-keywords-314
```

instead of

```
 domain.com/name-of-a-news-with-cool-keywords-4673612453
```

?

Answer (score 0):

How many articles do you *have*?

To uniquely represent them all like this, you're saying that you have over `1,000,000,000` articles all with *exactly the same keywords*.

Having these numbers might not affect SEO, but logically, I'd shorten them too. It's like generating a `100` character hash when building a database for 1,000 items.

In short, don't overkill. Keep it short.

Comment: It's not the number of articles ... we didn't want to show the real ID of the item (since we don't want to show how many items we have in the database). That's because we generate random INT ID's. And that's the reason of the debate. If they affect or not the SEO performance for being "larger" than usual.

Comment: I meant, why are you using such a huge number? A little random integer is fine too.

Comment: Yes, it goes from 50000 or so to 2147483647  (int of 32 bits) ... I put in the example a number too high :D sorry ... and now, for SEO it does matter ?